# Saving multiple E-Mails with identical name locally too slow

Tags: windows-7, email, network-shares, lotus-notes, drag-and-drop

I have a  user who wants to backup E-Mails on our network shares. She does this by draging the mails and dropping them to the share that she wishes to backup her mails on. This creates an eml-file with the subject as file name.

The mails all have the same subject (they are generated by another system), so when she does this she gets a window with 3 Options (don't copy, overwrite, copy but rename). She chooses the third option and checks the checkbox "do this for all files". Then the copy process starts but takes very long. Sometimes the process suddenly stops while copying and the user has to start again.

She only has this problem when she tries to copy multiple mails at the same time. When she does this one by one she doesn't have this problem.

She uses IBM Notes 9.0 and Windows 7 Pro.

How can we copy the files without having the problems I listed above? What causes the process to be so slow/suddenly stopping?

Comment: Although I don't know exactly, my guess is as follows: let's say the subject is `mail`, and the files are renamed as `mail(1)`, `mail(2)`,... The naive approach of renaming the files is: try to create `mail`, if it exists, try to create `mail(1)`, if exists create `mail(2)`, etc. If the application that creates the files does it like this, then `mail(k)` will result in `k` file system accesses, and copying `n` mails will result in `(n*(n+1))/2` file system accesses ([the sum of all positive integers up to n](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_⋯)).

Answer (score 0):

The quickest solution would probably be to create a custom toolbar button for your user that adds a date/time stamp to the Subject of each email. That way, if she runs this on each of the messages first, there would be no filename conflict when she does the drag-and-drop operation to the share.

The button code would be something like this:

```
FIELD Subject := @Text(@Now) + " " + Subject;
```

(Not tested!)

An agent that can run on multiple messages with a single click would be better, but then you would have to deal with adding the agent either to the mail template and maintaining that template through any Notes upgrades, or adding it directly to the user's mail file and protecting it against design replace/refresh operations - which requires more explanation and gets us closer to StackOverflow territory than SuperUser territory.